# What is the output of this flowchart?

Tags: output, flowchart

[image: This the flowchart]
What can be the output of this flowchart? Will z turn into zero ever?

Comment: Not sure if this is some homework or what, but you should probably try to make an effort here by taking a pen and testing it yourself. Will be far more efficient and useful. Also [ask]

Answer (score 0):

After 7 cycles, `Z` will be zero, and `X` will be -19200.

[image]